# How to write a file in background service Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin

I am using Firebase cloud messaging service to receive notifications. I want to write a file when a notification is received. I am able to write a file when app is running, but when app is in the background or in a closed state, I am getting notifications, but unable to write file.

[image]

The part of code highlighted in red is the problem

```
Java.IO.File SdCard = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
Java.IO.File dir = new Java.IO.File(SdCard.AbsolutePath + "/Notifications");
dir.Mkdirs();
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(dir,MyFirebaseMessagingService.Name+".txt");
if (!file.Exists())
{
    file.CreateNewFile();
    file.Mkdir();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    writer.Write("ProfilePreview," + MyFirebaseMessagingService.Name);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am not getting any error, just unable to write file. while i am receiving notification when the app is in background or closed.

Comment: Add some logging and figure out what is going on. Otherwise, you are going to change stuff blindly until it works.

Comment: Have you added runtime permissions to read and write files?

Comment: Yes i have added permissions

Comment: Is there any other way to implement on message received event from FCM and when message is received i need to write a file in device. (this should happen even when the app is in background or closed state)

Comment: You could try to start a [foreground-services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services).

Comment: ok i will try that